# Limit the number of snapshots in Jfrog Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, snapshot

I have a requirement to limit the number of snapshot to 1 in my Artifactory.

I configured in my Artifactory and limiting max number of snapshots to 1. I have done the restart of the server and it is not taking effect and the artifactories are not getting deleted and more number of snapshots are still present.

How can we remove the snapshots?

Comment: Is this question about a Maven repository? where did you configure the max number of snapshots?

Comment: Yes it is a Maven repository. To specify the maximum number of snapshots that may be stored, select the Repositories module and click the repository whose settings you want to edit.

In the Basic settings, check Handle Snapshots and then set the Max Unique Snapshots field. This value is zero by default, which means that all snapshots are saved. Followed the URL - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF4X/Managing+Disk+Space+Usage#:~:text=To%20specify%20the%20maximum%20number,that%20all%20snapshots%20are%20saved.

Comment: Please note that Artifactory requires that you store a minimum of 2 unique snapshots. Setting the max number to 1 may result in concurrency issues. In addition, older snapshots will be deleted once newer ones are deployed. The deletion mechanism will run in the background after a couple of minutes

Comment: @Dror, Thanks. I have modified to 2 snapshots and still "Maximum unique snapshots" not working for me. Kindly provide your inputs on how can I resolve the same.

Comment: I tried waiting for more than an hour and I restarted and tried the server as well, both doesn't work.

Comment: did you deploy a newer snapshot since changing the settings?

Comment: Yes I deployed after configuring the settings, and still 5 snapshots are present.

Comment: How can we check the configurations made on "Maximum unique snapshots" is working or not ? Do we have any checks for that ?

Comment: There are no known issues with this feature for the latest version of Artifactory. It is most probably something specific for this project, might be related to the snapshots naming/versioning. Debugging such an issue requires examining the actual snapshots which are being deployed

Comment: @DrorBereznitsky, for testing purpose I have taken 1 pom.xml file and just updating the file name and version inside the file with new version and deploying the new version. Will it cause an impact that "Maximum unique snapshots" will not work in such a case or something like that ? Kindly provide your inputs, still im facing the issue.

Comment: This will not work. To trigger it you will need to mimic a complete deployment which includes a .pom and an artifact. I suggest testing it with the maven-example sample project available in https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/